# 404 on startup page changing admin panel URL

Tags: magento-1.8, 404-page

I've tried to change `admin panel URL` of my Magento site replacing `<![CDATA[admin]]>` with `<![CDATA[new_admin_url]]>` in **app/etc/local.xml** file.

I have only this issue: when I `login`, the startup page (dashboard in my case) gives me a 404 Page Not Found (this is the URL: `http://mywebsite.com/index.php/admin/new_admin_url/index/noRoute/key/008cc1001579efd08067c36c315f293e/`). After that I navigate in the `admin panel` and all works fine. It seems the system doesn't find the correct route.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that remove All cache from cache folder

Comment: Done!
_rm -rf [magento_root]/var/cache/*_ and _rm -f [magento_root]/var/session_.
Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting my initial comment from your question, I found a solution that worked for me (I had exactly the same issue as you).

I've defined the "Use Secure URLs in Admin" to "yes" in System > Configuration Web > Secure tab (what is a good complementary security setting).

Now when I go to mywebsite.com/customadminpath + connect, the Dashboard is initially displayed as expected.

I hope it's working for you too.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: mmm.. en effect, I noted that on the first access it continues to give a 404 page. Only from the next logins it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Magento: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store :: setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website]

The exact solution for this problem is present over here:-

> Magento Error – Notice: Undefined index: 0
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Config.php on line 92

Just run the mysql query present over there and the problem is solved.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry @hari-haran but I don't understand your answer.

Where I find the mysql query I have to run?
And why have you listed these error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add action in Admin login template

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml`

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" id="loginForm">
```

Comment: In my 'Admin login template' the action already exists.